# pip search not working on pypi repository

Tags: artifactory

I have setup a PyPi repo in Artifactory, but I cannot search uploaded packages with pip.

I created a PyPi repo in Artifactory and pushed two versions of an example package, which worked perfectly. The package and it's two versions is present in Artifactory under the correct repo. Running pip search and trying to find this package results in a timeout.

Uploading the packages dind't present any issues at all.

I have tried without /simple as well.

```
pip search example -i http://artifactory_server/api/pypi/pypi-repo/simple
```

produces the following:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 179, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\search.py", line 48, in run
    pypi_hits = self.search(query, options)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\search.py", line 65, in search
    hits = pypi.search({'name': query, 'summary': query}, 'or')
  File "c:\python27\lib\xmlrpclib.py", line 1243, in __call__
    return self.__send(self.__name, args)
  File "c:\python27\lib\xmlrpclib.py", line 1602, in __request
    verbose=self.__verbose
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\download.py", line 823, in request
    headers=headers, stream=True)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 581, in post
    return self.request('POST', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\download.py", line 403, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\adapters.py", line 529, in send
    raise ReadTimeout(e, request=request)
ReadTimeout: HTTPConnectionPool(host='artifactory_server', port=80): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)
```

Any ideas are most welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the link right?

Comment: Yes, it's exactly the same as when I uploaded the package (but without /simple). I'm actually going to increase the timeout, just to see if it's the server itself being very slow for some reason.

Comment: I can't seem to be able access the link, Possibly some firewall blocking incoming connections?

Comment: artifactory default port is 8081. Are you running on 80 port ? If yes then you can run telnet  artifactory_server 80

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not using https, you need to add the following option at the end of your command
--trusted-host artifactory_server